# APACHE-TOMCAT can anybody elaborate which one is web-server and web-container?

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver, web-container

HI
Most of the time I read Tomcat is Web-server.. Sometimes I read Tomcat is web-container..
Sometimes I read Apache is web-server.. I am bit puzzled..
Can anybody explain it properly?

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been several years since I've worked with Tomcat, but I believe I can answer your question.  Tomcat is a JSP Servlet Container.  It also has a built-in web server.  So I think the answer to your question is that Tomcat is both server and container.  It may (and I have never done this, but I think I recall reading about it) be possible for Tomcat to run under Apache, and allow Apache to handle all the static HTML pages and such.  Apache is a web server, and thus much better at high-volume static page loads and such than Tomcat, which is intended for dynamic pages.

Comment: Tomcat can be run under Apache using mod_jk

Answer (score 3):

[Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/) - or HTTPD (D for deamon) - is the number one ***HTTP server*** and it is commonly referred to as "Apache". Actually, almost nobody uses the full name even if this is a kind of abuse . So, "Apache" means the web server ("a patchy server" originally).

[Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is a ***Servlet/JSP container***, it is used to serve dynamically generated content using the Servlet API. Apache Tomcat can also act as a web server and serve static files (like images, css) but this is not its primary function (and Apache, the web Server, does a better job at this<sup>1</sup>). It is often referred to as "Tomcat".

---

<sup>1</sup> Apache (the web server) can be used as a frontend to Apache Tomcat. When used together, Apache forwards the requests for dynamic content (Servlets/JSPs) to Tomcat but serves the static content.